# OpenCV - Read 16 bit TIFF image in Python (sentinel-1 data)

Tags: python, image, opencv, numpy, tiff

I'm trying to read a 16 bit TIFF image (26446 x 16688) in Python. Using OpenCV only reads a black image (all the intensities reads 0) by:

```
    self.img = cv2.imread(self.filename, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Can openCV handle 16 bit or large images (~840mb)? Any workaround?

EDIT: Also
       `cv2.imshow("output", self.img[0:600])`
displays a black image.

Comment: Just a hint... try running **InageMagick**'s `identify` command to inspect the min/max/mean/number of directories in your TIFF. It installed on most Linuxes. You want `identify -verbose YourImage.tif`

Comment: I have smaller 16-bit tiff files, and they work OK (they even display correctly in `imshow`, albeit probably truncated to 8-bit - `34067, 34983, 35287]], dtype=uint16)` - this is how my image ends (137, 137, 137 when loading without `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED`). Maybe you are loading a black picture, or the actual range is not exactly 16-bit (e.g. 12 bit, and shifting by 8 bit produces mostly zeros). It's either the size of the images, or it works correctly - try multiplying your image by some power of 2, or normalizing it (stretch contrast) before displaying. Or the first 600 rows ARE black...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Andrew Paxson a different library can be used. There is a library dedicated exclusively for playing with `tiff` images.

Use the following code for the same. Make sure you have `tif` installed in your system.

```
import tifffile as tiff
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

filename = 'Image.tif'
img = tiff.imread(filename)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use image libraries specific to raster data (in your case, sentinel-1). For example you can use `rasterio` for reading and displaying satellite images.

**Example:**

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

img = rasterio.open("image.tif")

show(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OpenCV can read uint16 perfectly fine:

```
img_np = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH | cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Speaking of file size limitation, depends on number of pixels:

> By default number of pixels must be less than 2^30. Limit can be set using system variable OPENCV_IO_MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56